# What is the proper file permission for an image upload site?

Tags: permissions

Would giving 777 permission on the folder that stores images be dangerous?

Comment: It would be on a shared hosting site.  Somebody could figure out the location of your folder and stick malicious things there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is really the first app I am writing, and I am putting it on Amazon ec2. What linux permission then would be appropriate for that?

Comment: Ideally, you'd want your file upload app to run under a particular userid and then chown the directory to 744.  Unfortunately what most people end up doing is having all their web apps running under the "apache" or "www-data" userid, and having to make their upload directory 777 so that they can do things to it, and the web app can add files as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd store them in the img folder and not give 777, but 664 for the permissions.

[Check out wiki for more details on chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod)

Answer (score 0):

yes,you should store your images out of your document root (htdocs).

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with them I'd say.

Comment: I have a form that allow user to upload image, with some basic data type checking only. As I am using Amazon ec2, file permission gets complicated and it doesn't work as it did on a basic web host. I just want to allow people to upload and view the image.